# Prove or disprove that the following system $\left\{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\pi t}{n-1-t}\right)\right\}_2^\infty$ is a Riesz basis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove or disprove that the following system
$$\left\{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\pi t}{n-1-t}\right)\right\}_2^\infty$$
is a Riesz basis on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. I do not think it is a trivial question, however, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Something which may help.. It is related to (bounded by?) sinc-functions, which are fourier transformable. Does it fill out some Fourier domain or just a sub-domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mathreader hinted, this is not a Riesz basis. It lacks the ability to resolve fine details of functions. More specifically, it does not contain any sharply localized our quickly oscillating functions: all it has is translates of a sinc function with one particular frequency.

One way to demonstrate the above is to apply the Fourier transform. The transform of sinc is compactly supported, and since shift becomes modulation, the whole family  of functions is supported within the same finite interval.

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting. Could you give me some more details, please? For instance, is $\operatorname{sinc}(n-t)$ a Riesz basis?